# Moving Scrollview pages with NStimer

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5, uiscrollview, nstimer

I have a sample code in that `UIScrollView` with 5 pages. And when S scroll the `UIScrollView` the page changes. And also put `pageControl` in the sample code. But I want to scroll the `UIScrollView` without scrolling it. Like `NSTimer` and it scroll automatically.

Comment: https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/kiimagepager try this code this may help you to fullfill your requirement that use also use scroll view and create images on scrollview. hope that may help you.

Answer (score 1):

1- Schedule `NSTimer`

```
// fire every second 
self.scrollTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(timerFired) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

2- On fire scroll by one page

```
- (void)timerFired
{
    CGFloat pageSize = scrollView.contentSize.width / scrollView.frame.size.width;
    // if this is the last page return
    if(scrollView.contentOffset.x >= scrollView.contentSize.width) {
        [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(0.0, scrollView.contentOffset.y) animated:YES];
    } else {
        [scrollView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(scrollView.contentOffset.x + pageSize, scrollView.contentOffset.y) animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `scrollRectToVisible`

```
[scrMain scrollRectToVisible:rect animated:YES];
```

Follow this [tutorial](http://sugartin.info/2012/01/21/image-sliding-page-by-page-uiscrollview-auto-scrolling-like-image-slider/).